# How do I write from my fastcgi client to IIS express?

Tags: c#, iis, fastcgi, iis-express

I have C# code that works fine using a socket. Now I'm trying to get it to work with IIS express and it appears to only support named pipes. After some time googling the only answer I found was read the data via stdin. That works. I thought writing to stdout would be how to communicate but it doesn't appear to work. In C# it doesn't appear I can write to stdin so I'm pretty confused at why IIS doesn't seem to receive my data.

---

Judging from [this page](https://blogs.iis.net/yaminij/getting-started-with-writing-a-fastcgi-client-application-fastcgi-test-client) it appears I can write to stdin which is a bit hard to believe

```
HRESULT SendReceive( bool fSend, PBYTE pBuffer, DWORD dwSize )
{
    BOOL fRet  = FALSE;
    DWORD dwLastError = 0;
    DWORD nNumberOfBytesRead = 0; 

    if( fSend == TRUE )
    {        
        fRet = WriteFile( hStdin, pBuffer, dwSize, &nNumberOfBytesRead, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        fRet = ReadFile( hStdin, pBuffer, dwSize, &nNumberOfBytesRead, NULL );
    } 

    if(!fRet)
    {
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
    } 

    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( dwLastError );
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to make a FastCGI client, Mono XSP can be your example (that blog post is using C++, and it is not even a complete sample). Note that FastCGI is not a trivial protocol though yes, it is Socket based and uses standard input and output to communicate with IIS (or IIS Express). If you want to simply write a web app, use ASP.NET frameworks.

Comment: @LexLi It looks fairly trival. Trival enough I got it working for nginx in a few hours. Overlooking socket disconnect is what got me since I didn't think sockets needed to disconnect for fastcgi. Anyways I want my fastcgi client to work for iis and I can't figure why it won't work. I rewrote it so the code is the same except for 3 lines (to listen/accept a socket + use socket as the stream VS use stdin/out as the stream). Works perfectly on nginx with tcp, doesn't on IIS and its bothering me.

Comment: "Perfectly" is never a good term to describe an open standard protocol like FastCGI, as the vendors can have their own ideas implementing certain features. When Mono guys started to include FastCGI support in XSP, they already fought the fight (I am not sure if they did fight against IIS though), http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/, so if you do have plenty of time, you can do the same. The only officially supported FastCGI client of IIS is PHP. So I guess in edge cases, you can only refer to the PHP source code.

Comment: @LexLi I ended up looking at XSP and it uses unsafe code and writes to socket 0 which i assume is stdin. I tried to do the same but I must have done something wrong or didn't understand the code correctly. I don't plan on making a fastcgi client for C#. I was thinking maybe I could for rust or some other language.